# Gradle build Liferay's Hello word portlet

Tags: gradle, liferay, portlet

I have downloaded the Hello-word portlet's source code from the Liferay [github](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-hello-world) repository.
And then when I have executed the build

> gradle build

The build failed with the following exception.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':apps:foundation:hello-world:hello-world-web:pmdMain'.
No rulesets specified
```

Can anyone, please, tell me what's the cause of this exception and how to build this bundle correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered is because the `build` task [depends](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) on `check`, which in turn [depends](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html#sec:pmd_tasks) on the PMD tasks. The problem is that these PMD tasks don't work on these sub-repositories (yet).

Instead of `gradle build`, try something like `gradle jar`.